# Why is Riemann's Rearrangement Theorem not considered a contradiction?

Tags: summation

If we can pick any conditionally convergent series, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, and pick any real number, $\ell$, and show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \ell,$$

then why is that not considered a contradiction, since we can show that this sum takes on *any* value, and any real number can be equal to any other real number? In my limited experience in math, usually something like this is considered a contradiction, and I had expected that such a sum would just be said to diverge or DNE.

It's really confusing me today.

Comment: You are mis-quoting Riemann's Rearrangement Theorem. It should be $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_{\sigma(n)} = \ell$ for some permutation $\sigma$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem does not say that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \ell,$$it says that if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$is conditionally convergent, for every $\ell \in \Bbb R$ there is a bijection $\sigma:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{\sigma(n)}=\ell.$$It's a different series. For $\sigma = {\rm Id}_{\Bbb N}$ you have the original value of the series. For other values, non-trivial permutations.